# font-face compilation with compass

Tags: css, compilation, sass, font-face, compass-sass

sorry if my english is bad, i am french.
Here is the problem: i write a font-face include in my scss file, like that:

```
@include font-face("Enhanced Dot Digital", font-files("font/enhanced_dot_digital.ttf"));
```

and then, when it compiles it, i got this in my css file:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Enhanced Dot Digital";
  src: url('///fonts/font/enhanced_dot_digital.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

and the problem is that it's not the good path, for my font (which is font/enhanced_dot_digital.ttf), and i think that's why it's not working. But i can't take the '///fonts' off, and i don't know what's the origine of this. Can you help me please :/?

Answer (score 0):

Check the config.rb file for the "fonts" path. It looks like it is including that path in there already for you. So try changing it to this.. `font-files("enhanced_dot_digital.ttf")` and change the path in the config.rb to `fonts_dir = "font"` or whatever folder you have your fonts stored in.